# How can enable https with fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt for a facebook app in Apache 2 server?

Tags: facebook, apache

How can enable https with fb_ca_chain_bundle.crt for a facebook app in Apache 2 server ?

Basically I have this file, how can I set up my apache 2 to use this cert?